# jquery Calculate sum from elements markup

Tags: jquery, sum

I have the child count coming from the server, i'd rather not do any more math there.  I'd like to extract the number from the markup.

Within every .active-parent I need to loop through, and get a number from .category-count .

```
      children_counts = $('.active-parent .category-count')
      children_counts.each(function(){
        var parent_count = $(this).text();
        console.log(parent_count)
      });
```

I have it returning the numbers with the log statement

```
189
5
86
261
```

Can't figure out how to sum those up.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a variable and use **parseInt** to add the count inside the each loop.

```
children_counts = $('.active-parent .category-count');
var totalCount = 0;
children_counts.each(function(){
   var parent_count = $(this).text();
   totalCount += parseInt(parent_count, 10);
});
console.log('Total Count is -- ' + totalCount );
```

Comment: AMAZING. Thanks for the quick answer, now I just need to figure out how to append that to the .active parent !  Thanks

Comment: @jahrichie .. Glad to have helped...   Just use `append` method ..  `$('.active-parent').append( $('<p/>', { text : total_count }));`